# Add/subtract minutes to/from hours decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm getting error `2.7755575615628914e-17` when I try to add 15 minutes and then subtract 5 minutes 3 times. Should be zero instead. Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/3zq4napd/

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(event) {
    var input = $('input');

    var inputVal = parseFloat($('input').val());
    var addVal = parseFloat($(this).data('num'));
    var newVal = inputVal + (addVal / 60);

    $(input).val(newVal);
});

$(document).on('click', '.sub', function(event) {
    var input = $('input');

    var inputVal = parseFloat($('input').val());
    var subVal = parseFloat($(this).data('num'));
    var newVal = inputVal - (subVal / 60);

    $(input).val(newVal);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Your problem stems from using floating point maths instead of date & time. See [What every programmer...](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: I don't need to use date & time, when I can use simpler approaches.

Comment: Agreed, but trying to patch up floating point arithmetic is a poor option. You'd do better to do all your arithmetic in seconds so that you can use integers throughout, converting only when you display the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal behaviour when dealing with floating point numbers: they can be exactly represented in binary, but not all of them are exactly representable in decimal. Rounding should help.

**EDIT**: The best way to avoid floating point error is to avoid dealing with numbers that are not exactly representable in binary form - i.e. avoiding any division except by powers of `2`. Since `60` is not a power of `2`, dividing by `60` will open the door for floating point error. Thus, if you can have your calculation entirely in minutes, or in seconds, or (JavaScript standard) milliseconds, you stay entirely in integral land.

(You could even count in twenty-minute blocks, because your minimal unit is 5 minutes, which is `20 / 2^2`, so you're still binary-safe. But if you count in hours (i.e. sixty-minute blocks), there is a further division by `3`; since fractions of `3` are not representable in binary, the error pops up.)

Comment: Rounding makes incorrect values for hours in decimals.

Comment: The number is rounded anyway. `1/60` is not really `1/60`, and it is certainly not `0.016666666666666666` (since the actual representation is infinite). The best thing you can do is round it again to a certain number of digits when you want to display it.

Comment: Right, but it wont let me do subtraction without math error before I even display.

Comment: Even better: don't divide. Divide only when you display. Do everything in minutes. No math error there.